# How to export JFreeChart Data to csv file

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, export-to-csv

I have used `Java Swing` along with `JFreeChart` for plotting graphs in the tool we are designing. Now i want to export the graph data to CSV file.(*say upon right click on graph it should give an option of exporting to CSV and upon selecting it, a csv file should be created in some random location and save the graph data into it*).

The important point here is how to save data into CSV from graph. I need to use `Java Swing` and `JFreeChart` for achieving this.

Comment: First off, it's Java *Swing* not swings since the latter is a piece of playground equipment while the former is a Java GUI library. Secondly, we must assume that you have the data that was used to generate the graph, so that begs the questions: what have you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I want to give user an option of getting the graph data in form of CSV file. Forget how i get data. The CSV should be generated from graph itself. I am able to display the graph, but i am not able how to get data out of graph (to save it into CSV).

Comment: But the graph is *generated* from the original data. If you save that, the user can generate his graph. Again, where are you stuck? I'm not sure you've given enough information for this to be an answerable question yet.

Comment: assume that i have no data after graph is plotted. Tell me how to get data out of graph.

Comment: I've never used JFreeChart, but I'd look at the [JFreeChart API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html), to see how to extract data from the graph. Promising methods look to be `JFreeChart#getXYPlot()` and `XYPlot#getDataSet()`. The API suggests that an XYDataSet has methods which should allow you to extract your x-y data. With a little leg work, you should be able to solve this yourself.

Comment: What kind of `dataset` are you using to generate the chart? Is it a simple `XYDataSet` or some other type? Also +1 with @HovercraftFullOfEels - why can't you store the data in some `data structure` when you're creating the chart and then when the user chooses to save the data, you use the data from this structure to create your csv?

Comment: _i have no data after graph is plotted_ - how comes you are loosing the data while plotting?

Comment: @chaitu Could you please also put your code somewhere, so that we can see how you generate your graph?

Comment: downvoting because this question shows absolutely no effort put into solving the problem

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
JFreeChart chart;
// ... initialization of chart
XYDataSet dataSet = chart.getXYPlot().getDataset();
```

Then use of the `dataSet` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: But isn't `chart.getXYPlot()` this an assumption that the OP has indeed created an `XYPlot` of some kind?

Comment: The OP is giving us limited information and forcing us to make assumptions for the better or worse. I up-voted this partly for this reason, and partly because we both posted the same solution at the same time (though mine as a comment).

Comment: @chaitu: Sujay & HFOE both offer valuable comments; `getXYPlot()` is a convenience method. "NOTE: if the plot is not an instance of `XYPlot`, then a `ClassCastException` is thrown."

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete example:

```java
   private void storeDataSet(JFreeChart chart, String filename) {
      java.util.List<String> csv = new ArrayList<>();
      if (chart.getPlot() instanceof XYPlot) {
         Dataset dataset = chart.getXYPlot().getDataset();
         XYDataset xyDataset = (XYDataset) dataset;
         int seriesCount = xyDataset.getSeriesCount();
         for (int i = 0; i < seriesCount; i++) {
            int itemCount = xyDataset.getItemCount(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < itemCount; j++) {
               Comparable key = xyDataset.getSeriesKey(i);
               Number x = xyDataset.getX(i, j);
               Number y = xyDataset.getY(i, j);
               csv.add(String.format("%s, %s, %s", key, x, y));
            }
         }

      } else if (chart.getPlot() instanceof CategoryPlot) {
         Dataset dataset = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDataset();
         CategoryDataset categoryDataset = (CategoryDataset) dataset;
         int columnCount = categoryDataset.getColumnCount();
         int rowCount = categoryDataset.getRowCount();
         for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
               Comparable key = categoryDataset.getRowKey(i);
               Number n = categoryDataset.getValue(i, j);
               csv.add(String.format("%s, %s", key, n));
            }
         }
      } else {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown dataset");
      }
      try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename + ".csv"));) {
         for (String line : csv) {
            writer.append(line);
            writer.newLine();
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot write dataset", e);
      }
   }
```